# REGEX: Extract paths from string

Tags: regex

I would like to extract paths in the form of:

$/Server/First Level Folder/Second_Level_Folder/My File.extension

The challenge here is that the paths are embedded in a "free form" email like so:

> Hello,
>
> ```
>  You can download the file here:
> ```
>
> - $/Server/First Level Folder/Second_Level_Folder/My File.extension <- Click me!

Given a string, I would like to extract all paths from it using RegEx. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it always say " <- Click me!" at the end or is the end of the line sometimes different? Otherwise I think it would be impossible to distinguish the path from other text on the same line.

Comment: Something [like this](http://regex101.com/r/vW7bR1) should maybe help you ...

Comment: @Tharwen No. That is just a sample to imply that paths may be inline with other texts.

Comment: @Kent VBA. I think the tool/language is not really necessary, right? Reg. expressions are tool/language agnostic, I think.

Comment: yes it is. basic regex, extended regex, PCRE ... vim has it's own (powerful) regex engine ....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible `(\$/.*?\.\S*)` should do the job just fine.

`\$/` matches the start of the path

`.*?` matches everything till the next part of the regex

`\.\S*` matches the dot and anything but a whitespace (space, tab)

And the `(` `)` around it make it capture all that is matched.

**EDIT:**

For further use

*Just the path*

`(\$/.*?/)[^/]*?\.\S*`

*Just the filename*

`\$/.*?/([^/]*?\.\S*)`

Comment: Thanks! It works! Just a follow-up, what if I also want to match only up to the "directory" level like so: $/Server/First Level Folder/Second_Level_Folder

Comment: Assuming there is a file after that it is possible to do it by `(\$/.*?/)(?:[^/]*?\.\S*)`
Again the `(\$/.*?/)` matches the path
But the `(?:[^/]*?\.\S*)` matches the filename using ?: the group is made non capturing. 
So if you want to have the filename and not the path use `(?:\$/.*?/)([^/]*?\.\S*)`

Comment: (\$/.*?/)(?:[^/]*?\.\S*) and (?:\$/.*?/)([^/]*?\.\S*) did not work. I tried validating it against the sample string using http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Which programming language or tool are you using? It's possible it doesn't support non capturing groups. 
If that's the case `(\$/.*?/)[^/]*?\.\S*` should work. (I edited the answer so it doesn't use non capturing groups anymore.)

Comment: I'm using VBA but testing using regexpal.com.

Comment: I just had a look at regexpal.com, this is just a misunderstanding. regexpal highlight the part that is matched. Not the part that is captured, so it indicate that the howl string is matched but only the filepath (or filename) is captured aka returned.

Answer (score 4):

If the filename contains [escaped forward slashes / or no period symbol] AND the filepath spaces are escaped with a backslash '\ ' you can still do it with this (i've escaped the forward and back slashes)

```
(\/.*?\/)((?:[^\/]|\\\/)+?)(?:(?<!\\)\s|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0uDOKoxqKDPb8OGS)

This creates two capture groups - one for the path and one for the file basename. If your test strings contains filenames with unescaped spaces (as shown) then you would have to use the period in the filename as an anchor as per B8vrede's answer.