# Find multiple forward slashes in text file

Tags: python, regex

I am looping through files with lines like these:

```
PROGDIR=/this/is/a/file/path
LOGDIR=/this/is/another/path
```

I'm just trying to find the first line with a path (progdir for this example). The way I'm identifying if the line is a path is if it has multiple forward slashes. Maybe there's a better way to do this?

I'm thinking something along the lines of this should work:

```
re.compile('[/]+')

or

a = [line for line in line if '/' in line]
```

What can I try next?

Comment: 1.) Consider that slashes are considered special characters in almost every case, so escaping them will probably be necessary. Also, in case you're just looking for single-line entries with multiple slashes you could set multiline to false & just go at it with a regex like '\/\w*\/\w*' etc., matching everything so long asthe line has sufficient occurences of words following slashes following words :)

Comment: try this regex `(?s)((\/\w+){1,}).*` this should get you first path from the input. or entire line `(?s)^.*?((\/\w+){1,}).*`

Comment: @P.... it looks like `re.compile('(?s)((\/\w+){1,}).*')` grabs lines that start with a /. but doesn't grab them if there's text before the path.

Comment: @max use the 2nd regex

Comment: @P....the second option seems to grab every line with a forward slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `count` like this as example:

```
data = ["PROGDIR=/this/is/a/file/path",
        "LOGDIR=/this/is/another/path",
        "TEST=/xxx.p",
        "TEST2=/nsdjsal"]


def get_first_file(lines: list) -> str:
    for line in lines:
        if line.count("/") > 1:
            return line
    return ""


print(get_first_file(data))
```

output:

```
"PROGDIR=/this/is/a/file/path"
```

Comment: This kind of works. I changed it to > 1. But when looping, I'm getting every line with multiple forward slashes. how do I get just the first instance where there are multiple forward slashes? Here's what I have: `if line.count("/") >= 2: print (a)`

Comment: did you tried my code (the function)? The function returns on the first matching, so you only get one line, if you take the lines as array as input. (i changed the condition)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create regex just to catch paths.

There's a good solution here.
[Solution of B8vrede](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562971/regex-extract-paths-from-string)

You can take just the paths part.

```
(\$/.*?/)[^/]*?\.\S*
```

Comment: how do you actually implement this? I tried re.search but that doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it with regex, you could also see if Python thinks it's a path. Assuming the file is read in as `foo`:

```py
split = re.split(r'[\n=]', foo)
paths = list(filter(lambda x: os.path.isabs(x), split))
```

This works for the examples in the question, because `isabs` (unlike `isdir` or `isfile`), doesn't actually check to see if there's anything at that path.